# Implement JUnit test for Spring Service using doReturn

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I want to implement JUnit test for this Spring Service by using `doReturn` to mock request:

```
        @Service
        public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
            private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("binlistsService")
            private BinlistsService binlistsService;

            public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {        
            }

            public PaymentResponse validateBinCountryCheckFilter(Merchants merchant, Contracts contract, Terminals terminal,
                      PaymentTransaction message, HttpServletRequest request) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

                     List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");

                     Optional<BinLists> db_bin_list = binlistsService.findByName(billing_address_country);
             }
       }
```

I tried this JUnit test:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {
    Terminals terminal = null;

    @InjectMocks
    private BinCountryCheckFilter binCountryCheckFilter;

    private BinlistsService binlistsService = Mockito.mock(BinlistsService.class);  
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);

    @Mock
    List<RiskFilters> riskFiltersList = null;

    Optional<BinLists> binList = null;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);             
        riskFiltersList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>(); 

        RiskFilters filter = new RiskFilters();
        riskFiltersList.add(filter);    

        BinLists binLists = new BinLists();
        binList = Optional.of(binLists);
        terminal = new Terminals();
        terminal.setId(11);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {

        //      when(riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString())).thenReturn(riskFiltersList);      

doReturn(riskFiltersList).when(riskFilterService).findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString());
        when(binlistsService.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(binList);

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");

        Optional<BinLists> bin = binlistsService.findByName("US");

        BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl();

        binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter(merchant, contract, terminal, authorizeTransactiontMockup(), request);
    }
```

The code is working fine when I try to mock the requests with `doReturn`..... but it fails when I call the actual Spring Service in order to test it with NPE at this line at the Service Java Class `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl`:

`List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");`

How I can mock this SQL query request?

***EDIT***: I tried this minimal example but it's now working:

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("binlistsService")
    private BinlistsService binlistsService;


    @Autowired
    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(
            @Qualifier("binlistsService") BinlistsService binlistsService,
            @Qualifier("riskFilterService") RiskFilterService riskFilterService) {
        this.binlistsService = binlistsService;
        this.riskFilterService = riskFilterService;
    }

    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {        
    }

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter() throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");   
    }
}
```

JUnit test:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {

    @Mock
    private BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilter;

    private BinlistsService binlistsService = Mockito.mock(BinlistsService.class);

    @Mock
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);

    @Mock
    List<RiskFilters> riskFiltersList = null;

    Optional<BinLists> binList = null;
    Terminals terminal = null;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 

        riskFiltersList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>(); 

        RiskFilters filter = new RiskFilters();
        filter.setId(1);

        riskFiltersList.add(filter);    

        BinLists binLists = new BinLists();
        binLists.setId(1);

        binList = Optional.of(binLists);

    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {

        binCountryCheckFilter = 
                  new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(binlistsService, riskFilterService);

        doReturn(riskFiltersList).when(riskFilterService).findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString());


        BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl();

        binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter();
    }    
}
```

I get again NPE at the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug it to check if the there is any instance for riskFilterService?

I think the problem is because your class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl is not actually receiving the mocks.

You have two options to fix this:

1. You use Spring Context and spring will @Autowire the mock, but from my point of view, this is no longer a unit test;
2. You can change the way you instantiate your component, using a constructor to autowire  the dependencies:

@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

```
private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

private BinlistsService binlistsService;

@Autowired
public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(
        @Qualifier("binlistsService") BinlistsService binlistsService,
        @Qualifier("riskFilterService") RiskFilterService riskFilterService) {
    this.binlistsService = binlistsService;
    this.riskFilterService = riskFilterService;
}
```

Then, in your unit test, just instantiate the class you want to test with the mocked services like:

```
Optional<BinLists> binList = null;

@BeforeEach
public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);             
    riskFiltersList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>(); 

    RiskFilters filter = new RiskFilters();
    riskFiltersList.add(filter);    

    BinLists binLists = new BinLists();
    binList = Optional.of(binLists);
    terminal = new Terminals();
    terminal.setId(11);

    binCountryCheckFilter = 
      new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(riskFilterService, binlistsService);
}
```

And you will not need the @InjectMocks annotation.

EDIT: Added full solution

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    private BinlistsService binlistsService;


    @Autowired
    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(
            @Qualifier("binlistsService") BinlistsService binlistsService,
            @Qualifier("riskFilterService") RiskFilterService riskFilterService) {
        this.binlistsService = binlistsService;
        this.riskFilterService = riskFilterService;
    }

    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {        
    }

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter() throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");   
    }
}
```

TEST:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {

    private BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilter;

    @Mock
    private BinlistsService binlistsService;

    @Mock
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    @Mock
    List<RiskFilters> riskFiltersList = null;

    Optional<BinLists> binList = null;
    Terminals terminal = null;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 

        riskFiltersList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>(); 

        RiskFilters filter = new RiskFilters();
        filter.setId(1);

        riskFiltersList.add(filter);    

        BinLists binLists = new BinLists();
        binLists.setId(1);

        binList = Optional.of(binLists);

        binCountryCheckFilter = 
                  new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(binlistsService, riskFilterService);

    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
        doReturn(riskFiltersList).when(riskFilterService).findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString());
        binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not working. Any solution how to fix this?

Comment: Added the full code, you cannot mock the BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilter as this is the class you want to test. Then, you should call the constructor on the before, not required, but you should prepare the test there and finally, if you call the default constructor as you did before calling validateBinCountryCheckFilter, you are actually removing the mocked services from it because it returns a new instance.

Comment: Can we remove the `@Autowired` stuff?

Comment: Yes because it is already over the constructor of the service. Spring will call that constructor and autowire the dependencies from there.

Comment: Well I remove the Autowired stuff but I get NPE: https://pastebin.com/13fHBvtC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201688/discussion-between-nel-and-peter-penzov).